# VB.NET HTML Hyperlinks

Tags: .net, html, vb.net

I'm currently attempting to use a .NET WebBrowser to display help information (stored locally in html files) for an application I'm writing, however I'm experiencing two problems, both related to hyperlinks.

Firstly, I have a search function which returns the correct URL in the format `file:\\\C:\...` I can copy and paste it into a browser, and it will navigate there. Yet clicking on the link within the control itself does nothing at all.

Secondly, the HTML files all contain relative paths to other HTML files. These of course do not work as I just end up with `file:\\\C:\help.html` which gives me a 'webpage is unavailable.'  But I can't think of a way to get it to work without parsing the HTML file and concatenating the path to the directory on to the front of the link.

**Edit:** Just to clarify, in the first problem I am dynamically building a search result page as the user types. The HTML contains several results similar to this (yes, it's unfinished, I'm just showing you the link part):

`<a style='font-family:verdana;color:#0645AD;font-size:20px;text-decoration:underline' href='C:\Users\User\Documents\project\bin\Debug\..\..\Help\FAQ.html'>FAQ</a><br />...This is the <b>FA</b>Q File.`

Now, when I click on that link in the control nothing happens, it doesn't give me a 'webpage is unavailable' or take me to the actual page. Saving the HTML, however, and opening it with Chrome, IE and Firefox works fine.

In the second problem, I have a different help file for different sections, each containing relative links to several others. VB picks these up as direct paths, and attempts to go there from root, i.e file:\\C:\file.html. The only solution I can think of is to parse the file and use `WebBrowser.Navigate(Path.Combine(pathToDirectory, nameOfHelpFile.html)`, which seems a lot more inefficient than it should be.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix involved adding a bit of code to the 'Navigating' event of the WebBrowser control.

```
  Private Sub HelpBrowser_Navigating(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowserNavigatingEventArgs) Handles HelpBrowser.Navigating
    If e.Url.Scheme = "about" And e.Url.AbsolutePath <> "blank" Then 
        ' The clicked URL is of the format about:<file>.
        HelpBrowser.Navigate(HelpRootPath + "\" + e.Url.AbsolutePath)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need to show us some code to see exactly what your problem is. I worked up a quick example of using the `WebBrowser` control with one HTML file that links to the other and its working just as expected.

Relative links are relative to the current document being browsed. If you're writing raw HTML to the browser then I think that links a relative to what it thinks is root which might be `file:///c:/` but I'm not sure. Also, you might be running into a permission problem if you're files are actually living in the drive's root.

Here's the sample that's working fine for me:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private WithEvents WebB As WebBrowser

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ''//Create our web browser
        Me.WebB = New WebBrowser()
        ''//Set it to fill the form
        Me.WebB.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        ''//Add it to the form
        Me.Controls.Add(Me.WebB)

        ''//We will put our HTML files in this folder which is on the desktop
        Dim WorkingFolder = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "HTMLTest")
        ''//Create it if it doesn't exist
        If Not Directory.Exists(WorkingFolder) Then Directory.CreateDirectory(WorkingFolder)

        ''//The names of the two files that we are creating
        Dim FirstFile = "Start.html"
        Dim SecondFile = "End.html"

        ''//Write HTML in the first file that has a link to the second file
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, FirstFile), <html><head><title>Start</title></head><body><a href=<%= SecondFile %>>Link to second file</a></body></html>.ToString(), False)
        ''//Write HTML in the second file
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, SecondFile), <html><head><title>End</title></head><body>This is the second file</body></html>.ToString(), False)

        ''//Tell the web browser to navigate to the second file
        Me.WebB.Navigate(Path.Combine(WorkingFolder, FirstFile))
    End Sub
End Class
```